# Adding another condition to a foreach loop (PHP)

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have two arrays of data to work with, and I'm trying to create a loop that will utilize them both like so.

Array A is a list of keywords.
Array B is a list of city names.

I'd like for the following foreach loop to take each keyword and combine it with a city name.When each keyword has been matched successfully to every city in Array B, I'd like the loop to continue on through the Array A values and continue the matching.

It seems simple enough, but using the code below, I have been unable to get it working right. The loop works successfully in grabbing one value from the list of keywords, but it then simply adds every value from array B to that keyword and loops through that way.

My code can be seen below:

```
<?php
foreach ($keyword_list as $key => $value) {
$keyword = strtolower($value);
//REMOVE COMMAS
$keyword = str_replace(',', '', $keyword);
//ADD HYPHENS
$keyword = str_replace(' ', '-', $keyword);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
$content[$i] = trim($content[$i]);
//RE-REPLACE SINGLE QUOTES TO ESCAPED VERSIONS FOR INCLUSION IN HTML DOC (PHP ARRAY)
$content[$i] = str_replace("'", "\'", $content[$i]);
}

$file = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $businessName . '-' . $businessPhone));
$file .= '-' . $keyword;

foreach ($city_list as $key2=>$value2) {
$file .='-' . $cityword; 
}

$filename = $file . '.php';
}
?>
```

So with that code above, the following would be produced as an example...

```
Google-5555555555-Keyword Here-CityNameOne-CityNameTwo-CityNameThree.php
```

Instead, I'd like it to work as such...

```
Google-5555555555-Keyword Here-CityNameOne.php
Google-5555555555-Keyword Here-CityNameTwo.php
Google-5555555555-Keyword Here-CityNameThree.php
```

I thought this would be easy but I'm learning as I go and I'm stumped by what could be causing this issue. If there is anything that I can do to help in resolving it, please advise! I do wish to learn how to do this properly so I'm simply looking for any guidance at all.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last `foreach` you add `$cityname` to the string `$file`, you could instead collect the "filenames" in a result array:

```
$filenames = array();
foreach($keyword_list as $keyword)

    // ... snip/snap ...

    foreach($city_list as $city) {
        $filnames []= $file.'-'.$city;
    }
}

print_r($filenames);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a concept answer rather than me adapting your code. If you are trying to get all of the combination possibilities for the two lists a foreach loop inside a foreach loop works great for this.

```
$keywords = array('keyword0', 'keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword4', 'keyword5', 'keyword6', 'keyword7', 'keyword8', 'keyword9');

$cities = array('austin', 'houston', 'dallas', 'san antonio', 'amarillo', 'katy', 'kyle', 'round rock', 'buda', 'paris');

$all_possible_combinations = array();


//if you would like to get all of the possible combinations of these two lists you may try something similiar to this

foreach($cities as $citykey => $cityname){

    foreach($keywords as $keywordskey => $keyword){
        $all_possible_combinations[] = 'Google-5555555555-'.$keyword.'-'.$cities[$citykey].'.php';
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($all_possible_combinations);
echo '</pre>';
```

You can edit and see the out put here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57522c0bb18e5c04dd6ba3c046f1f9593ce2ceec

I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this loop:

```
foreach ($city_list as $key2=>$value2) {
    $file .= '-' . $cityword;
}
```

A quick fix would be:

```
<?php
foreach ($keyword_list as $key => $value) {
    $keyword = strtolower($value);
    //REMOVE COMMAS
    $keyword = str_replace(',', '', $keyword);
    //ADD HYPHENS
    $keyword = str_replace(' ', '-', $keyword);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        $content[$i] = trim($content[$i]);
        //RE-REPLACE SINGLE QUOTES TO ESCAPED VERSIONS FOR INCLUSION IN HTML DOC (PHP ARRAY)
        $content[$i] = str_replace("'", "\'", $content[$i]);
    }

    $start_of_line = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $businessName . '-' . $businessPhone));
    $start_of_line .= '-' . $keyword;

    foreach ($city_list as $key2=>$value2) {
        $file .= $start_of_line . '-' . $cityword . '.php'."\n";
    }

    $filename = $file;
}
?>
```

(I haven't ran the above snippet of code to test it.)